# bootstrap modal on load page issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a bootstrap modal on load page it works properly but I want to add class to an element if it active and remove it if it not active I tried the following but it doesn't work properly!
[here is the example](https://codepen.io/kemozzz/pen/gvoqRx)

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  $("#myModal").modal("show");
});
if ($("#myModal").hasClass("in")) {
  $(".test").addClass("active");
} else {
  $(".test").removeClass("active");
}
```

```css
.test {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color:#e0e0e0;
}
.active {
  background-color:#000;
}
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
<div class="test"></div>
```

Comment: after fix : [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p2pLkvxu/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `shown.bs.modal` and `hidden.bs.modal` to detect modal is open or not then `add` or `remove` class.

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  $("#myModal").modal("show");
});

$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
  $(".test").addClass("active");
  console.log('Active');
}).on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
  $(".test").removeClass("active");
  console.log('Not Active');
});
```

```css
.test {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
}

.active {
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
<div class="test"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @Glad to help. Just see my updated answer for shorter version.